# Unable to resolve "react" from "node_modules\react-native-scripts\build\bin\crna-entry.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem.

Expo building in error.

Unable to resolve "react" from "node_modules\react-native-scripts\build\bin\crna-entry.js"

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3"
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need clear react native packager

`rm -rf node_modules` // remove node_modules folder

`npm cache clean`

`npm install`

`npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Open package.json on the root folder of your project and replace

```
"main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
```

with

```
"main": "./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
```

Source:https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component#i-created-my-project-before-sdk-18